# Trying to print numbers in integer that are bigger than 25 and are multiples of 3

Tags: c#

Here is what I have done so far. what am I doing wrong?

```
int[] integer = { 6, 27, 60, 30, 57, 80, 89, 40 };

for (int i = 0; i < integer.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i > 25)
    {
        Debug.Log(integer[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run it?

Comment: when I run it, I get number 6,30,89

Comment: Please don't tag with irrelevant languages.

Comment: @wavehanded With the code given, it should be impossible ( condition i>25 is always false, since i is the array length and you array is 8 in length) so please give the real code or the real output next time.

Comment: `foreach (int item in integer) if (item % 3 == 0 && item > 25) Debug.Log(item);`

Comment: When you say "what am I doing wrong?"  Please be detailed about that.  Please describe what you expect it to do and what it actually did.  Also, give us some clue about what your level of understanding of the issue is.  Try to describe the parts you *do* understand, right up to the point where you do not, and we'll help close the gap in your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement currently is checking based on the index `i`.

```
if (i % 3 == 0 && i>25)
```

You should do it as

```
if (integer[i] % 3 == 0 && integer[i] >25)
```

Comment: Alternatively, they could switch to a foreach loop: `foreach (int i in integer) { if (i % 3 == 0 && i>25) { ... } }`

Comment: @ikegami I would also prefer this. Way better to read

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem is that you are applying the conditions over `i` **not** over the corresponding `integer`.

Try using:

```cs
   for (int i = 0;i< integer.Length; i++)
    {
      int myInteger = integer[i];
      if (myInteger  % 3 == 0 && myInteger >25)
      {
           Debug.Log(myInteger );
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont wanna use i in your if statement but integer[i]